# I get a � when pasting data in excel with visual basic. Why?

Tags: excel, vba

When using Excel 2007, just yesterday it started pasting � when I copy data from another workbook.  This � completely ruins the new worksheet, as the data is not formatted or organized correctly.  I use VBA to run MACROs, nothing has changed in the MACROs, but now I my data is ruined.  Can someone please help me figure out what is wrong?

Here is the code:

```
Sub LoopR()

    Dim File As String
    Dim Path As String
    Path = "C:\My Documents\Macros\"
    File = Dir(Path)

    Do While Len(File) > 0
        If File = "* Master.xlsm" Then
            Exit Sub
        End If

        Workbooks.Open (Path & File)

        'Macro which organizes my data into the correct
        'format and cells
        Call k80jason

        Range("A1:H" & Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row).Copy
        ActiveWorkbook.Close savechanges:=False
        ActiveSheet.Paste Destination:=Worksheets("Sheet1").Range(Cells(1, 1), Cells(1, 8))

        File = Dir
    Loop

End Sub
```

Comment: I am not able to guess your code to determine what changes you need to make.

Comment: [Here](http://www.joelonsoftware.com/articles/Unicode.html) is a very interesting and useful article to read.

Comment: beat me by 5 seconds lawrence... Damn those weird character sets/unicode I've had similar issues with them

Comment: Sub LoopR()
    Dim File As String
    Dim Path As String
    Path = "C:\My Documents\Macros\"
    File = Dir(Path)
    Do While Len(File) > 0
    If File = "* Master.xlsm" Then
    Exit Sub
    End If
    
    Workbooks.Open (Path & File)
    Call k80jason 'Macro which organizes my data into the correct 'format and cells
    Range("A1:H" & Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row).Copy
    
    ActiveWorkbook.Close savechanges:=False
    ActiveSheet.Paste     Destination:=Worksheets("Sheet1").Range(Cells(1, 1), Cells(1, 8))
    File = Dir
    Loop
    End Sub

Comment: Now it is working correctly.  I have no idea why...

Comment: most commonly when I have seen this it is errant 0d and 0a characters that are not getting translated to their respecive carriage return/line feed display results.

Comment: I debugged the problem, but cannot fix it.  

I'm using Excel 2007 on Windows XP (not by choice).  I was able to get rid of the � by opening the workbook and running the MACRO only after opening Excel 2007.

The first time I ran the MACRO it worked, then every following time it gave me the � symbol.  I closed and reopened Excel 2007, and the � were gone!